# Implement chat using websocket in android with php

Tags: php, android, websocket, chat

I want to implement chat functionality using websocket in android with php.

I need php code for the same.

The scenerio is like this.

The android developer will send message from android device to php application and than from php the message will be sent to another users android phone it is meant for.

After that i need to save all the chats in database as well.

I have no idea how to  do it.

Please help and provide code fo this.

The code i have written is as follows.

```
$address = "0.0.0.0";
$port = 5000;
$max_clients = 10;

if(!($sock = socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0)))
{
    $errorcode = socket_last_error();
    $errormsg = socket_strerror($errorcode);

    die("Couldn't create socket: [$errorcode] $errormsg \n");
}

echo "Socket created \n";

// Bind the source address
if( !socket_bind($sock, $address , 5000) )
{
    $errorcode = socket_last_error();
    $errormsg = socket_strerror($errorcode);

    die("Could not bind socket : [$errorcode] $errormsg \n");
}

echo "Socket bind OK \n";

if(!socket_listen ($sock , 10))
{
    $errorcode = socket_last_error();
    $errormsg = socket_strerror($errorcode);

    die("Could not listen on socket : [$errorcode] $errormsg \n");
}

echo "Socket listen OK \n";

echo "Waiting for incoming connections... \n";

//array of client sockets
$client_socks = array();

//array of sockets to read
$read = array();

//start loop to listen for incoming connections and process existing connections
while (true) 
{
    //prepare array of readable client sockets
    $read = array();

    //first socket is the master socket
    $read[0] = $sock;

    //now add the existing client sockets
    for ($i = 0; $i < $max_clients; $i++)
    {
        if($client_socks[$i] != null)
        {
            $read[$i+1] = $client_socks[$i];
        }
    }

    //now call select - blocking call
    if(socket_select($read , $write , $except , null) === false)
    {
        $errorcode = socket_last_error();
        $errormsg = socket_strerror($errorcode);

        die("Could not listen on socket : [$errorcode] $errormsg \n");
    }

    //if ready contains the master socket, then a new connection has come in
    if (in_array($sock, $read)) 
    {
        for ($i = 0; $i < $max_clients; $i++)
        {
            if ($client_socks[$i] == null) 
            {
                $client_socks[$i] = socket_accept($sock);

                //display information about the client who is connected
                if(socket_getpeername($client_socks[$i], $address, $port))
                {
                    echo "Client $address : $port is now connected to us. \n";
                }

                //Send Welcome message to client
                $message = "Welcome to php socket server version 1.0 \n";
                $message .= "Enter a message and press enter, and i shall reply back \n";
                socket_write($client_socks[$i] , $message);
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    //check each client if they send any data
    for ($i = 0; $i < $max_clients; $i++)
    {
        if (in_array($client_socks[$i] , $read))
        {
            $input = socket_read($client_socks[$i] , 1024);

            if ($input == null) 
            {
                //zero length string meaning disconnected, remove and close the socket
                unset($client_socks[$i]);
                socket_close($client_socks[$i]);
            }

            $n = trim($input);

            $output = "OK ... $input";

            //echo "Sending output to client \n";

            //send response to client
            //socket_write($client_socks[1] , $output);

            //send response to client
            socket_write($client_socks[$i] , $output);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you get any solution, Please let me know we need the same.

Answer (score 0):

check this link http://socketo.me/docs/hello-world

Ratchet is a loosely coupled PHP library providing developers with tools to create real time, bi-directional applications between clients and servers over WebSockets.